# What is the correct syntax for using a PHP class function to supply the value for a variable in the same class?

Tags: php, function, class, variable-assignment

I am working on a college project that must use a CSV file to create the values for a table. It must have a class and it must have specific class variables (one of them I have already created for testing). Only the variables are specified as having to be part of the class but I think it would be better to pack the function inside the class (unless someone has a different opinion).

Basically, I want to use the class function to create the values for the class variables. Here is my script (refer to the comments for explanation):

```
    <?php
        class productRow {
            function make_table_row($i) {
                $row = 1;
                $tablerows = [];
                if (($input = fopen("input.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
                    while (($tabledata = fgetcsv($input, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {   //cycles through the rows of data creating arrays
                        if ($row == 1) {
                            $row++;     
                            continue;       //skips the first row because it's a header row I don't want on my input
                        }
                        $tablerows[] = $tabledata;      //uses the roles to populate a multidimensional array
                        $row++;
                    }
                    fclose($input);
                    return $tablerows[$i];      //uses the $i argument to return one of the row arrays
                }
            }
            var $itemNumber = this->make_table_row($i)[0];  //Line 118: calls make_table_row function to get the first item from the row returned
        }
        $pr1 = new productRow;
        echo $pr1->make_table_row(1);       //calls the function from within the class
    ?>
```

I get this error: Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tylersite\index.php on line 118

I know the return works because I tested it with `print_r`, including adding an array number as I did with that variable value to get a specific array value. So I must not be calling that function instance correctly. I've tried various things including removing the `$this` keyword as I wasn't sure I needed it, but the truth is I don't really know how to do it and I'm having trouble finding documentation on the correct syntax. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: As a rule, assignment to [class properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) like that can only be a constant expression, not a call to a function like that. Additionally, where would the `$i` parameter be coming from in that scope?

Comment: @msbit Okay. I think maybe I made a mistake then putting my logic there in a function. I think I can do this if I get rid of the function syntax.

Comment: Make use of the class constructor function. In that function you can set `$this->itemNumber = $this->make_table_row($i)[0];`. Also note that in your example you're missing a `$` at when attempting to call the function.

Comment: For what it's worth, `var` is a PHP/4 syntax that was superseded in PHP/5 (released in 2004). Your project is likely to have increasing difficulties to run in supported PHP versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using constructor function

```php
class productRow {
    var $itemNumber = []; // default value doesn't matter as it will change in __construct

    public function __construct($i) {
        $this->itemNumber = $this->make_table_row($i)[0];
    }

    function make_table_row($i) {
        $row = 1;
        $tablerows = [];

        if (($input = fopen("input.csv", "r")) === FALSE) {
            // return early - reduces indentation
            return;
        }

        while (($tabledata = fgetcsv($input, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {   //cycles through the rows of data creating arrays
            if ($row == 1) {
                $row++;
                continue;       //skips the first row because it's a header row I don't want on my input
            }
            $tablerows[] = $tabledata;      //uses the roles to populate a multidimensional array
            $row++;
        }
        fclose($input);
        return $tablerows[$i];      //uses the $i argument to return one of the row arrays
    }
}

$pr1 = new productRow(1);
var_dump($pr1->make_table_row(1));
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Now, I am a little confused by how putting my argument onto productRow allowed those functions to take it as an argument. Would you by any chance be able to explain that?

Comment: @Tyler the constructor function is essentially the first function run when you call `new ClassName($a, $b, $c);` - in this case `$a, $b, $c` are passed as parameters/arguments to the `__construct` function. This is a special function for PHP classes which allows you to "set them up".

Comment: It might be a bit confusing here since we're using `$i` in both cases as the argument - but they definitely don't need to match across functions

Comment: I was able to modify those calls a bit and only needed to give the argument to the class to make both functions work. I guessing the value of `$i` was maintained for the second function?

Comment: In each function (`__construct` and `make_table_row`) `$i` is not shared. Each function has it's own scope so you could change the argument to `$start` on `__construct` in which case any code referencing `$i` **within** that function would need to be updated to `$start`, however, this would have no effect on `make_table_row` as it's a separate function with its own scope.

Comment: Okay, but what I am saying is that managed to do `pr0 = new productRow(0);` and then used the instance variable `$pr0->itemNumber` without having to call `make_table_row` directly. I guess the `__construct` function is calling it for me?

Comment: @Tyler yes since `$this->itemNumber` is being set in `__construct` that value is saved on that **instance**. So for this `$pr0 = new productRow(0);` - `$pr0` is an instance. If you created a separate one `$pr1 = new productRow(1);` it has its own set of values from `$pr0`. With both of those `$pr1->itemNumber` *can* be different to `$pr0->itemNumber` and changing one won't effect the other.